# Transaction failing due to can't estimate Gas Cost on Polygon

Tags: solidity, gas-limit, hardhat, polygon, decimals

I have a function

```
function tokenValue( address _token, uint _amount ) public view returns ( uint ) {
        return _amount.mul( 10 ** IERC20( MY_TOKEN ).decimals() ).div( 10 ** IERC20( _token ).decimals() );
    }
```

To convert the decimals of one token into my token. However, when trying to call this on the deployed contract in a hardhat console, I get this error

```
  reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',
  code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
```

In my hardhat.config I have a manual gas limit of 2100000 so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Due to this closed issue solution approach comment https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1232#issuecomment-853726035 about `UNPREDICTABLE GAS LIMIT` problem, you have to remove `gasPrice` from your payloads to simplify `eth_estimateGas`.

Polygon also is sometimes returning 0 from estimation gas without no clue why which may also lead to problems `UNPREDICTABLE GAS LIMIT`.